# Connection Failure when trying to make simple REST call to Jira API

Tags: coldfusion, jira-rest-api, coldfusion-11

I have this simple GET call that works perfectly from Postman, Powershell, C# and even browser JS ( after disabling CORS ), but porting it to a ColdFusion CFHTTP call is failing.

Below is the response from the Jira API:

```
{
  "ErrorDetail": "I/O Exception: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target",
  "Mimetype": "Unable to determine MIME type of file.",
  "Filecontent": "Connection Failure",
  "Statuscode": "Connection Failure.  Status code unavailable.",
  "Responseheader": {
    
  },
  "Text": true,
  "Charset": "",
  "Header": ""
}
```

**CF Code:**

```
<cfset jql="<redacted>">
<cfset jiraEndpoint ='https://jira.bullhorn.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=#jql#'>

<cfhttp url = "#jiraEndpoint#" result="res" method="get" username="<redacted>" password="<redacted>">    
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="application/json" />    
</cfhttp>

<cfheader name="Content-Type" value="application/json">
<cfoutput>
    #serializeJSON(res)#
</cfoutput>
```

**Things I have tried:**

- Used a Authorization header with value `"Basic <base64 encoded string version of username:password>"`
- Added `Content-Type` header
- Added `mimetype` header
- Tried to use [a third-party CFC](https://github.com/DealerPeak/Jira-REST-API-cfc)

Nothing seems to work.

Comment: The error sounds like a certificate problem. Eg https://www.hass.de/content/coldfusion-java-pkix-path-building-failed-javasecuritycertcertpathbuilderexception-could-not

Comment: I agree that it is a certificate problem - though in my experience it's a problem that shouldn't happen in CF2016+ and Lucee 5+ unless there is an "extra download" misconfiguration on the endpoint server, which in this case there isn't, so it looks more like a consequence of the OP having to handle certs for cfhttp the hard way due to using CF11.

Comment: @SevRoberts - Agreed. I only noticed the CF11 tag just now

Answer (score 3):

Jira's certificate configuration checks out fine, including their intermediate cert - you can confirm this with ssllabs or a similar tester, eg https://globalsign.ssllabs.com/analyze.html?d=jira.bullhorn.com .

In your case the reason you see a problem will be because you are using an old version of Coldfusion which is using an old JVM, which neither downloads their Digicert intermediate certificate, nor has that certificate pre-installed. Ideally you should be upgrading from CF11.

For a workaround you can manually install the Digicert intermediate certificate + Jira bullhorn certificate to your server's cacerts - instructions for this vary depending upon your environment but one example is https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/import-certificates-certificate-stores-coldfusion.html - then restart the CF service and retry the cfhttp call.